# Where are Libre Office thumbnails stored?

Tags: 16.04, libreoffice, thumbnails

I'd like to delete a thumbnail of a Libre Office spreadsheet that contains some sensitive info. I've encrypted the spreadsheet and deleted the original, but LO continues to display a thumbnail graphic of it.

Comment: Just a guess, did you try ~/.thumbnails ?

Comment: Yes, I deleted those files but that didn't work.

Comment: You can disable thumbnails in ooo - https://ask.libreoffice.org/en/question/61938/how-do-i-turn-on-thumbnail-previews-in-libreoffice-writer/

Comment: There's also `~/.cache/thumbnails`

Comment: `find $HOME -name thumb*`

Comment: I've disabled new thumbnails, and flushed ~/.cache/thumbnails.  LO thumbnails still appear.

Comment: Panther's find command shows a few empty folders.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Thumbnails of LibreOffice files are stored within 
`$HOME/.config/libreoffice/4/user/registrymodifications.xcu`

This file is an xml file as you can see by running

```
file $HOME/.config/libreoffice/4/user/registrymodifications.xcu


/home/dkb/.config/libreoffice/4/user/registrymodifications.xcu: XML 1.0 document, ASCII text, with very long lines
```

If you open that file with a competent text editor, and search for "thumbnail", you'll come across something like:

```
<prop oor:name="Thumbnail" oor:op="fuse"><value>iVBORw0KGgoAA .... IAAAAASUVORK5CYII=</value></prop>
```

for each thumbnail.

One way to get rid of **all** existing thumbnails is to close all instances of LibreOffice (soffice.bin) and then delete `registrymodifications.xcu` knowing that you may lose other customizations and settings as well. This file will be recreated, much smaller now, the next time you start any application of the LibreOffice suite.

Another way, if you're adventurous and which I haven't tried, is to directly edit `registrymodifications.xcu` to remove the thumbnails bits without destroying the xml structure.

To prevent thumbnails from being created in the first place, see https://ask.libreoffice.org/en/question/52288/registrymodificationxcu-exclude-thumbnail-data/

Comment: Will deleting `prop oor:name="Thumbnail"` tags in that file be enough? Probably could be done with some XML parser.

Comment: I just did that on a throwaway profile and it seems to work. But OP will need to be careful about the start and end points or risk a non-functional file.

Answer (score 0):

To solve this you'll have to clear Nautilus thumbnail cache.

Open your home directory and Hit Ctrl+H to show the hidden files and folders.
Open .thumbnails and delete all the files in it.

Restart your system or kill Nautilus for change to take effect.

Comment: Do you mean cache/.thumbnails? I didn't find .thumbnails in the location you noted. Deleting the latter does not seem to work.

Comment: I meant to say that deleting the 'cache/.thumbnails' files did not seem to work.

Answer (score 0):

I think I found a simple menu-based answer. Open LO: File-->Recent Documents-->Clear List, seems too do the trick. Remaining issue is whether the data is still stored somewhere?

Comment: DK Bose provides the answer to my remaining question. First, I cleared the "Recent Documents" list as above. Then I generated a test thumbnail of a LO spreadsheet and found the associated XML code in `HOME/.config/libreoffice/4/user/registrymodifications.xcu`. Then I cleared the recent docs list again and checked to see that the above noted XML code had been automatically deleted.